# Angular 2 : loading app/main.ts from created route

Tags: angular, router

This is an Angular 2 RC5 Project :
I just started to add parameters to my routes, then this problem appears :
[image: Console print : XHR error loading http://localhost:3000/login/app/main.js]

In fact, here is my router :

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './components/login/login.component';
import {ProfileDetailsComponent} from      './components/profileDetails/profileDetails.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
     },
    {
        path: 'login/:userId',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'profile/:userId',
        component: ProfileDetailsComponent
     }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

So when I call /login/42, it loads me the LoginComponent :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl : "login.component.html"
})

export class LoginComponent { }
```

And this works.
The problem is when I reload the page, I got the previous error :

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/login/app/main.js
```

it tries to load app/main.ts from the login path I have just added !

Some topics say that this is caused by the catch error in the index.html :

```
System.import('app/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

(edit) I also have put the base tag in my index.html file :

```
<base href="/"/>
```

Some others spoke about the systemjs.config.js :

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

If you require me to post another file, don't hesitate !
Thanks !

Comment: sounds like a problem with base href...

Comment: yeah try to put  a <base href="/"> in your index.html (or if you have a folder where your app i built ..do it like: <base href="/app_build/">

Comment: Thanks both of you. Unfortunately, I got this already in my index.html file : <base href="/"/> . If you have other ideas, feel free to post them !

Comment: Just by the way - you should update to 2.0.0 or even later. You probably don't need the workaround with a release. Even 2.4.4 is out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been waiting a long time and fetching lot of URL's.

Finally, I didn't find a solution, but a way to get around the problem :

```
{
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileDetailsComponent
 }
```

And pass additional data with GET parameter :

```
/profile?id=20
```

Hope that will help